# How to use url masking for dynamic url

Tags: php, url, masking

I have not good idea about url masking. I know this is possible to make **Current url** to **Target url** but don't know how to do it for dynamic url. Is it possible to make the masking with php code.

Current url: `http://domain.com/product?id=123&cat=2`

Target url: `http://domain.com/product/123/2`

Comment: This must be the most asked question around here. Didn't find any examples?

Comment: I searched i've get example but can't figure out. that's why i make the question. @IkoTikashi . now i got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `mod_rewrite` Apache

like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://mydomain.site/page/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

[Apache RewriteRule and query string](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)